# How to apply two where condition one inside subquery and the other out of subquery?

Tags: sql, join

Find the customer that spend less than 3$ on individual film rentals, but has spent a total higher than 15?

The query that I wrote is given below

```
SELECT CustomerID,Customer.CustomerFirstName,Customer.CustomerSurname,Total FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Customer.CustomerID,Customer.CustomerFirstName,Customer.CustomerSurname,sum(([Rental].[Quantity])*([Film].[FilmPrice])) AS Total
FROM Film RIGHT JOIN (Customer INNER JOIN Rental ON Customer.CustomerID = Rental.CustomerIDFk) ON Film.FilmID = Rental.FlimIDFk 
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID,Customer.CustomerFirstName,Customer.CustomerSurname) T WHERE  Total>15;
```

Now how can I apply the second condition which is FilmPrice<3
Please help me out.

[This is the ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmW45.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another where clause inside the subquery, after your join on but before the group by for `WHERE FilmPrice<3`

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the customers where the maximum price of a film they have rented is less than 3 and the total price of all the films they have rented is greater than 15.

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT CustomerID,
       CustomerFirstName,
       CustomerSurname
FROM   Customer
WHERE  CustomerId IN (
  SELECT r.CustomerIDFk
  FROM   Rental r
         INNER JOIN Film f
         ON ( f.FilmId = e.FilmIdFk )
  GROUP BY r.CustomerIdFk
  HAVING MAX(f.FilmPrice) < 3
  AND    SUM(f.FilmPrice * r.Quantity)>15
)
```